# Prettify symbols in Visual Studio Community or Pro

Tags: visual-studio

I have came across very cool feature displayed on one of the Tutorials I've seen on Youtube. Person who was doing the tutorial, had a very cool feature for Visual Studio Community/Pro. Something similar to what you have on Visual Studio Code:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=siegebell.prettify-symbols-mode

Where Can I get a similar plugin for Visual Studio Community/Pro?